# What happened to Gideon after Season 4 in The Flash?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In Season 4 of *The Flash* The Thinker infects Gideon with a virus and she goes out of control.

What happens to her after that?

Answer (score 4):

### Presumably still out of action.

Certainly there is no reference to the Flash's Gideon in Season 5 *so far* (as of Ep.4) but there does seem to be confirmation that Gideon is still not available to the team.

In Season 5 Episode 1 *Nora* there is this refernce...

> I'm sorry I was too late.
>
> It took me a while to find where the Legends were. Well, when they were.
>
> But we got **their** Gideon to scan Nora's blood sample.

Clearly if the Flash's Gideon was still available they wouldn't need to use the "future" Gideon for analysis.